# Configure FTP on Ubuntu to default to a certain directory

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to configure an FTP server on my 12.04.3 LTS machine. I am hosting a website from `/home/webuser/public/mywebsite.com/public`. Now, I want to configure the FTP server in such a way where, when an FTP user logs in, they arrive in the `/home/webuser/public/mywebsite.com/public` directory (and that's the ONLY directory that they should be able to access).

I've tried vsftpd and pure-ftp, and I haven't had much luck. It seems that most processes involve creating a new, FTP specific user account, and the home directory is used to publish files to.  I can do that, but I need the uploaded files to go into the webuser's public folder.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the user's home directory. `usermod -d /new/home/dir username`
2. `echo username >> /etc/ftpchroot`